# Can the Hamiltonian operator act on a bra, if it was once acting on a ket?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation, hamiltonian

I was watching a MIT Quantum Physics III class when I got a doubt about a specific bra-ket manipulation. My doubt is about the step from the expression $(3.7)$ to the expression $(3.8)$ of the [lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-06-quantum-physics-iii-spring-2018/lecture-notes/MIT8_06S18ch6.pdf) (you can also watch the step from the instant 3:05 of the [video lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=4&v=Tcv3_Gk1Ysg) ).

The following holds:

$$H(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle=E_n(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle$$

The step in question is:

> $$\dot{H}(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle+H(t)|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle=\dot{E}_n(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle+E_n(t)|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle\Leftrightarrow$$
>   $$\Leftrightarrow\langle\psi_k(t)|\dot{H}(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle+E_k(t)\langle\psi_k(t)|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle=E_n\langle\psi_k(t)|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle$$

The second equation was obtained by a multiplication of the the first equation by $\langle\psi_k(t)|$, with $k\neq n$. My doubt is how does the $H(t)$ operator that was acting on $|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle$ in the first equation, suddenly acts on $\langle\psi_k(t)|$ in the second equation, resulting in $\langle\psi_k(t)|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle$? The $H(t)$ operator involves differentiation. The ket $|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle$ was being differentiated, and for some reason, $\langle\psi_k(t)|$ is now the one that is being differentiated. Is this a legal operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is legal.

To give some motivation of why this sort of integral-of-a-derivative operator might simplify in the way that you are considering, let's consider a very simple example far away from our normal concerns of normalizing wavefunctions and making sure things are Hermitian: Suppose your operator is $\partial_x$ and your bra is $x^2$, and we ignore the fact that things can be complex-valued for the moment: then acting on some arbitrary $f$ we are writing the left hand side as a shorthand for the right hand side in:$$\langle x^2\rvert\partial_x\lvert f\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx~x^2 f'(x).$$ But of course after integrating by parts we would have, $$
\begin{align}
\langle x^2\rvert\partial_x\lvert f\rangle &= \left[x^2 f(x)\right]_{-\infty}^\infty -\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx~2x f(x) \\
&= \langle -2x\rvert f\rangle,
\end{align}
$$
assuming appropriate decay properties of $f$ at infinity to remove the boundary term. So an integral-of-derivatives can sometimes be coerced into an equivalent plain integral. And you can also see that we have something that *almost* looks like the derivative of the left hand side, but has a frustrating minus sign.

The specific property that we are targeting here is the **Hermitian** or **self-adjoint** property which says that $H = H^\dagger$, or in mathematician's notation that $$\langle H \phi, \psi\rangle = \langle \phi, H \psi\rangle.$$This is not a trivial property and above we saw that just $\partial_x$ by itself does not satisfy this property; it satisfies a related property where it is called anti-self-adjoint or skew-Hermitian or so, $\nabla^\dagger = -\nabla.$ You may already know that $p$ as an operator does, which means that $i \partial_x$ has this property when we are careful with our negatives, because the negative sign gets absorbed into the complex conjugate operation: $$
\begin{align}
\langle \phi|i\partial_x|\psi\rangle &= \int dx~\phi^*(x)~i\partial_x~\psi(x)
\\&= i[\phi^* \psi] - \int dx~\psi(x)~i\partial_x\phi^*(x)
\\&= +\int dx~\psi(x)~ (i \partial_x \phi(x))^*
\\&= \langle i\partial_x\phi|\psi\rangle.
\end{align}
$$
(This is a little more easy to see in mathematicians’ notation, $\langle \phi, i\nabla\psi\rangle = i\langle\phi,\nabla\psi\rangle =i\langle-\nabla\phi,\psi\rangle$ by what we just proved and then the rest is just $ =\langle-(-i)\nabla\phi, \psi\rangle = \langle i\nabla\phi,\psi\rangle.$ As a corollary, any anti-self-adjoint operator can be made self-adjoint by multiplying by $\pm i$ and vice versa.)

The reason that we care about this property is that in quantum mechanics we want all of our predictions to be expectation values of the form $$\langle A\rangle_\psi = \langle \psi| A|\psi\rangle.$$ Taking the complex conjugate and remembering that $\big(\langle a | b | c\rangle\big)^* = \langle c|b^\dagger |a\rangle$ we find that the complex conjugate of this expression is
$$\langle A\rangle_\psi^* = \langle \psi|A^\dagger|\psi\rangle,$$
and so if we want a *real-valued* observable whose predictions always equal its complex conjugate no matter what the state is, we *need* to require that such an observable is self-adjoint.

The rules about the adjoints of operators are very simple, $(AB)^\dagger = B^\dagger A^\dagger$ and $(A + B)^\dagger = A^\dagger + B^\dagger$, so that you can take products of self-adjoint operators to get new self-adjoint operators only if the two commute, and you can take arbitrary sums of self-adjoint operators. Thus your typical single-particle Hamiltonian $H = -(\hbar^2/2m) \nabla^2 + U(\vec r)$, is manifestly self-adjoint because clearly $-\nabla^2$ is the product of two self-adjoint operators $(i\nabla)\cdot(i\nabla)$ and every operator commutes with itself, plus $U(x)$ is obviously self-adjoint, and finally the sum is self-adjoint.

These properties are what allow us to so confidently assert that $\langle \psi_k|H = E_k \langle \psi_k|,$ we know that $H|\psi_k\rangle = E_k|\psi_k\rangle$ on the right hand side, but since $H$ is self-adjoint we know that we can also apply it to the left-hand side just as well, to get a real number $E_k$.

Answer (score 0):

The full derivation is as follows:

$\dot{H}(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle+H(t)|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle=\dot{E}_n(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle+E_n(t)|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle\\
\Leftrightarrow \langle\psi_k(t)|\dot{H}(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle + \langle\psi_k(t)|H(t)|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle = \langle\psi_k(t)|\dot{E}_n(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle + \langle\psi_k(t)|E_n(t)|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle \\
\Leftrightarrow \langle\psi_k(t)|\dot{H}(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle + E_k(t)\langle\psi_k(t)|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle = \dot{E}_n(t)\langle\psi_k(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle + E_n(t)\langle\psi_k(t)|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle \\
\Leftrightarrow\langle\psi_k(t)|\dot{H}(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle + E_k(t)\langle\psi_k(t)|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle=E_n(t)\langle\psi_k(t)|\dot{\psi}_n(t)\rangle$

where we replace $\langle\psi_k(t)|H(t)$ with $E_k(t)\langle\psi_k(t)|$ and $\dot{E}_n(t)\langle\psi_k(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle =0$ because $k \ne n$ so eigenvectors $|\psi_k(t)\rangle$ and $|\psi_n(t)\rangle$ are orthogonal.

Remember that $E_n(t)$ and $E_k(t)$ are eigenvalues i.e. real numbers, so they commute with $\langle\psi_k(t)|$, and they are equal to their complex conjugates.

In the first term $\dot H(t)$ operates on the ket vector $|\psi_n(t)\rangle$ to produce another ket vector $\dot{H}(t)|\psi_n(t)\rangle$. We then take the inner product of this with the bra vector $\langle\psi_k(t)|$.